# Unable to install nginx-module-image-filter

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I'm running an Ubuntu 20.04 server and got an error while trying to run `apt install nginx-module-image-filter`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nginx-module-image-filter : Depends: nginx-r1.18.0
```

Running `nginx -v`:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: Please post the _complete_ output from `apt install nginx-module-image-filter`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like nginx was not installed with apt on your system, but from a downloadable archive instead. You can check the package's local availability and version with `dpkg -l | grep nginx`

If you can, you might want to reinstall nginx with apt before proceeding.

Alternatively, you might want to use --ignore-missing to ignore the error (See [apt's man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)) if you are certain that nginx's installation was done through nginx's package.